# What are some good tools / techniques for testing HTTP PUSH (HTTP streaming)

Tags: http, curl, push, http-streaming

What are some good tools / techniques for testing HTTP push? (HTTP streaming)

I require a tool to test a REST web service that utilizes HTTP PUSH (HTTP streaming). The tool needs the ability to make a connection and test for updates sent by the server. CURL would be my preference if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OWASP HTTP Post Tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_HTTP_Post_Tool) or you try [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/)